# How to pass items between pages in Oracle APEX in client side?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I know when *Oracle APEX page items* are submitted to server (for example with *ajax* or saving data to database) it's possible to transfer them to another page, but I need to pass items between pages without submitting to the server. Is there any way?

Comment: Can you provide more info ? If you pass an item from page 1 to page 2 via the url then it is not going through page submit in page 1 but it will be set in session state on the server when page 2 is rendered. What is the problem you're trying to solve ?

Comment: Probably the only way would be to use cookies (old school) or web storage - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use application item instead of page item. It is visible to all pages